# Is there any way to generate salt state output in xml format?

Tags: salt-stack

Is there any way to generate the salt state output in xml format directory without providing --output in CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

Output formats for Saltstack are listed here https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/output/all/. No XML by default but it should be easy to code, or just find a converter from YAML to XML, or JSON to XML.